# Form validator endpoint not found

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

I'm trying to write a form for User Information to keep track of who downloads files from my website.

I downloaded a PHP form validator from [this website](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-validation.html) and I tried to mimic the example 3 with client-side validation and here is what I came up with (please excuse the length, but I figured it was necessary for understanding everything):

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH. '/wp-includes/FormValidator/include/formvalidator.php');

$validation_errors='';
if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{// We need to validate only after the form is submitted

    //Setup Server side Validations
    //Please note that the element name is case sensitive 
    $validator = new FormValidator();
    $validator->addValidation("firstname","req","Please fill in your First Name");
    $validator->addValidation("firstname","alpha","Only letters a-z/A-Z are allowed for your First Name");
    $validator->addValidation("lasttname","req","Please fill in your Last Name");
    $validator->addValidation("lastname","alpha","Only letters a-z/A-Z are allowed for your Last Name");

    //Then validate the form
    if($validator->ValidateForm())
    {
        //If the validations succeeded, proceed with form processing
        addUserDataToDB();
    }
    else
    {
        //Validations failed. Display Errors.
        $error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
        foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
        {
           $validation_errors .= "<p>$inpname : $inp_err</p>\n";
        }        
    }
}//if

$first_name  = isset($_POST['firstname'])?$_POST['firstname']:'';
$last_name = isset($_POST['lastname'])?$_POST['lastname']:'';
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Whitepaper Download User Info</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        .error
        {
           font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
           font-size: 0.7em;
           color: #900;
           background-color : #ffff00;
        }
      </style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABSPATH.'/wp-includes/FormValidator/scripts/gen_validatorv31.js' ?>'>
</script>
    </head>
<body>

<form id="DownloadUserDataForm" style="width:100%;">
    <fieldset>
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <p><b>Input Fields with (*) are Required.</b> <br/><p>

            <div>
                <span class='error'><?php echo $validation_errors; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div style="width:100%;">
                <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:48%; margin-right:5px;">
                    <b>First Name *:</b> <input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:82%;" maxlength="50" <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['first_name']).'"'; }?>
                      /> <br />
                      <span id='firstname_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                </div>
                <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:48%;">
                    <b>Last Name *:</b> <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="50" style="display:inline-block; width:82%;" <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_POST['last_name']).'"'; } ?> /><br/>
                    <span id='lastname_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="clear:both;">
                <p><input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" style="clear:both;" /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
//Function for Processing Data
function addUserDataToDB() 
{
    global $wpdb;

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_downloadUserData', array( 'time' => current_time('mysql'), 'firstname' => $firstname, 
        'lastname' => $lastname ) );

    //Redirect to download page
    wp_redirect('Whitepaper.htm');
    exit();
}

?>

<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com
See: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
-->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    console.log("javascript ran");
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("DownloadUserDataForm");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    frmvalidator.addValidation("firstname","req","Please fill in your First Name");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("firstname","alpha","Only letters a-z/A-Z are allowed for your First Name");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("lasttname","req","Please fill in your Last Name");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("lastname","alpha","Only letters a-z/A-Z are allowed for your Last Name");
</script>
```

All that happens is the page refreshes, no errors or validations, and it doesn't seem to write to `$wpdb` because I have an admin page that queries the db table and it comes up empty (it also doesn't `wp_redirect()` like it should). Also for some reason it cannot find the javascript file even though the address looks correct.

> GET
>   http:///home/public_html/wp-includes/FormValidator/scripts/gen_validatorv31.js
>   404 (Not Found)

Comment: Now I have the client-side validation working somewhat, however it seems to error: "_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_" on the `frmvalidator.addValidation()` method because it happens on the page load, when the fields are empty. Any ideas? And of course my php validation/database entry doesn't work so I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

For your javascript error try changing this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo ABSPATH.'/wp-includes/FormValidator/scripts/gen_validatorv31.js' ?>'>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>/wp-includes/FormValidator/scripts/gen_validatorv31.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I still get 404 error not found. Maybe I put it in the wrong folder, but I FTP'd to my site, and placed my `FormValidator` folder inside of `/www/wp-includes/`. I also tried placing it in `/public_html/wp-includes/` but neither works.

Comment: Check the source to see what is being output and ensure that it is the correct path. 

Also make sure you have the correct file name.  The link to the javascript form validator that is in your comments, shows the file name as gen_validatorv41.js not gen_validatorv31.js

Comment: I just tried changing the path to a local one instead of absolute and the error went away. Is it okay to have local paths?